# YAML to HTML Eclipse plugin

Tags: yaml, swagger-editor

There are lot of Swagger related codegens to convert a YAML to HTML file , but is there an eclipse plugin available which can open or convert a YAML to HTML ?
I have searched in multiple places but there's no place where we can find such a plugin .Plugins like Yedit help seeing a YAML in colour syntax form but not as a HTML ?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [RepreZen API Studio](http://reprezen.com/swagger-tools), available as a standalone desktop application or as an [Eclipse plugin](http://rzen.io/q1r).

It includes swagger-codegen and other open source generators, which can create various forms of HTML documentation from your YAML-formatted Swagger-OpenAPI spec. Code generation is fully integrated into the IDE, but can also be run from the command line or CI/CD automated builds.

To clarify, there's no HTML "equivalent" of a Swagger-OpenAPI spec, or any other form of YAML. So it's not a simple matter of converting one file format to another. But there are various components that render a machine-readable OpenAPI spec, in YAML or JSON form, in a user-friendly HTML documentation format, often with integrated sandbox testing.

One of these is Swagger-UI, and it's included in the HTML formats that are supported by RepreZen API Studio.  I hope that helps.